# Keychain unable to import p12 properly and system keychain looks messed up

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, certificate, keychain

[image]I have .p12 file of ios Development certificate, I want to import it into my login keychain. But when I double tap it goes inside certificates instead of MyCertificates and it doesn't have expand arrow.

Because of this, I am not able to archive my iOS project. While codesigning I am getting an error saying "The specified item could not be found in keychain". [keychain after importing p12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rEfP.png)

And I also cant see any private keys for my system keychain certificates(cant see the expand arrow). 
Please help.[image]

Comment: Just drag .p12 file in the login section in the keychain. It will automatically insert into the login.

Comment: it is inserting into login keychain, but it is not going into "My Certificates" folder instead its going into "Certificates" and private key is getting added into "keys".I want both of them in"My Certificates"

Comment: Are you sure the .p12 file contains a private key? That format is commonly used to bundle up a certificate and its private key, but can actually contain (or not contain) a variety of things.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it has a private key, when I import it in my colleagues' mac keychain I can see the private key when I click on expand arrow.

Comment: Is it possible your colleagues' Mac already has a copy of the private key for some reason? Try converting the .p12 file's contents to a more readable form with `openssl pkcs12 -in /path/to/file.p12` -- it'll ask for the password a few times, but should dump the contents with readable headers like "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----".

Comment: I ran that command and got the private key, I am pretty sure that certificate has private key, When I import the certificate into keychain, private is getting added into the keys section but it not getting linked with certificate. I think the problem is with keychain. Thanks

Comment: The selected certificate in the screenshot is the Issuer Certificate and NOT the Issued Certificate (which the private key belongs to). Can you show us the issued certificate (ios Development certificate)?

Comment: I have added the screenshot please check.

Comment: Long shot, feel free to ignore me. But I have a custom swift class for adding p12s to keychain. If dragging and dropping isn't an option, you could add the certificate programmatically.

Comment: Let me know if you're interested and I'll give a more detailed answer.