# Nothing works for "The specified item could not be found in keychain"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I had been coding on an old Macbook Pro and was testing on an iPhone. I recently bought a new laptop and ever since then have not been able to test on my iPhone and therefore also won't be able to send to app store. I know the issue is with codesigning and I don't have my old private key so I revoked all certificates and started over from scratch and nothing has worked. I also have not been able to get any of my certificates to go to "My Certificates" in keychain access. They all go to "Certificates". Not sure if this is a problem. All my certificates are valid but still not working. Another note is that when I evaluate my certificates, I see under "Evaluation Status: No root certificate found" which may also be an issue.. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you install the Apple WWDR intermediate certificate? [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057241/iphone-what-is-a-wwdr-intermediate-certificate)

Comment: If they're not showing up in "My Certificates", that generally indicates you don't have the private key for the cert. When you "started over from scratch", did you get private keys for the new certs? BTW, it's too late now, but losing the private key doesn't mean you have to revoke the cert.

Comment: @GordonDavisson When looking in my keychain I would say yes I see the private key for both development and distribution and certs are valid however it doesn't look like they are linking together. My private key must be wrong? However, I did the request using Apple Cert Authority and generated my certs through xcode preferences. I never needed to download the private keys they just showed up after these processes. Did I miss some steps?

Comment: In that case it sounds like Keychain Access isn't properly associating the cert and private key for some reason. There's someone else with a similar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074876/keychain-unable-to-import-p12-properly), but unfortunately they don't seem to have found a cause or solution.

Comment: @GordonDavisson So I figured it out! It had something to do when I brought information from my old Mac to this one so I reset to factory settings and did not bring in my old stuff and only brought in my iCloud Drive. That seem to fix everything. Something must half got screwed up before. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ZackBlauvelt Weird. I wonder if the original keychain was just corrupt, so building a new one solved it? Anyway, I'm glad you got it working.